# Can the same USM user be added with different set of authentication and privacy algorithms?

Tags: snmp4j

> In my code, I am configuring the usm user and adding the user for SNMP
>   v3. I want to configure the user in a way that it will support the
>   below set of algorithms at the same time.
>
> SHA-1 + AES128, 
>   SHA-1 + DES, 
>   MD5 + AES128,
>   MD5 + DES
>
> Let's say the same usm user is capable of supporting these 4
>   combinations at the same time. Now, when I try from a management
>   console, I want to select any combination of the above 4 and the SNMP
>   Agent should work.
>
> Note: I do not want to add new usm users. I want the same user to be
>   configured with the above 4 combinations at the same time.

```
UsmUser user = new UsmUser(new OctetString(m_usmUser),
                         snmpAuthenticationAlgorithm,
                         snmpAuthenticationPassword,
                         snmpPrivacyAlgorithm,
                         snmpPrivacyPassword);
usm.addUser(user.getSecurityName(), user.getLocalizationEngineID(), user);
```

> Rather than the above, I want to user something like below.

```
UsmUser user = new UsmUser(new OctetString(m_usmUser),
                         AuthMD5.ID,
                         snmpAuthenticationPassword,
                         PrivDES.ID,
                         snmpPrivacyPassword);
usm.addUser(user.getSecurityName(), user.getLocalizationEngineID(), user);
user = new UsmUser(new OctetString(m_usmUser),
                         AuthMD5.ID,
                         snmpAuthenticationPassword,
                         PrivAES128.ID,
                         snmpPrivacyPassword);
usm.addUser(user.getSecurityName(), user.getLocalizationEngineID(), user);
user = new UsmUser(new OctetString(m_usmUser),
                         AuthSHA.ID,
                         snmpAuthenticationPassword,
                         PrivAES128.ID,
                         snmpPrivacyPassword);
usm.addUser(user.getSecurityName(), user.getLocalizationEngineID(), user);
user = new UsmUser(new OctetString(m_usmUser),
                         AuthSHA.ID,
                         snmpAuthenticationPassword,
                         PrivDES.ID,
                         snmpPrivacyPassword);
usm.addUser(user.getSecurityName(), user.getLocalizationEngineID(), user);
```

Answer (score 2):

The SNMPv3 standard does not support more than one auth+priv combination per USM user within a USM configuration as defined RFC 3414. This limit is caused by the structure and indexing of the usmUserTable. 
However, with SNMP4J you may defined more than one USM instance per agent and assign each USM instance its own usmUserTable instance and register each of that table instances within their own SNMPv3 context.

Although this would work, it might by easier to understand and implement using security protocol suffixes (or prefixes) in the SNMPv3 usernames like "myUser.AES128" vs. "myUser.DES", etc.

Comment: How to implement it using security protocol suffixes?could you give same examples or hint.